# Clicking on an item in the listview do not run the onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, href

I have a ListView of `Jquery`.

Clicking on each item passes to another page:

This is the list:

I fill it in the **code** as follows:

```
function FillList() {
    var UL= $('#MyList');
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
        UL.append(newLI);
        newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="NewPage.html" data-transition="slide" 
                           onclick="DoSomething('+i+');" >
                               <p> item number:'+i+'</p>
                          </a>';


    }
    $('#MyList').slideDown('slow');
}
```

The function DoSomthing:

```
function DoSomething(numberLi)
{
  alert(numberLi);
}
```

Function DoSomething not run when click on an item in the list,

it makes the move to another page **without first entering the function DoSomething**

why?

**UPDATE**:

Even when the code looks like this:

```
        newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="NewPage.html" data-transition="slide" 
                           onclick="alert('aaa');" >
                               <p> item number:'+i+'</p>
                          </a>';
```

The alert does not appear..

Comment: Was the original post a typo?

Comment: No problem, I'm updating my answer, one second.

Comment: where is Search variable? It think it must be UL.append(newLI);

Comment: Errors in copying the code ...

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console? Try to press f12 and see Console tab

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: I can not find } unnecessary

Comment: I believe that error stop the js from executing :)

Comment: try my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/en7VU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved

I sent him a **space variable** and therefore the function did not work for me ..

It was not in question so you could not know that,

thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

It's because inline event registration requires you to write JavaScript behavior code in your XHTML structure layer. See more at: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html.

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/8t2Ye/3/

HTML:

```
<a onclick="test1();">test 1</a>
<p>
<a onclick="test2();">test 2</a>

<script>
    function test1(){
        alert('test 1');
    }
</script>
```

JS(external):

```
function test2(){
    alert('test 2');
}
```

Only test1 is triggered.

**Update**

It seems your code has syntax error. Try my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/en7VU/1/

Comment: Yes, but I have it in another list (no differences between them) on the same page and is Yes working

Answer (score 0):

The event won't be triggered as long as it's navigating to the new page. What you could do is pass the anchor element as a parameter and then navigate to the URL after the function is done, like so.

```
newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="NewPage.html" data-transition="slide" 
                           onclick="DoSomething(this, '+ i +');" >
                               <p> item number:'+ i +'</p>
                          </a>';
```

And the function.

```
function DoSomething(anchor, numberLi) {
    alert(numberLi);

    window.location.href = anchor.href; 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I copied it incorrectly, but for me it's like you have written.

Comment: It is still going to link and not comes to function